# Position absolute div with no height vertically in the middle with no javascript

Tags: position, vertical-alignment, absolute

I am creating tooltips that will be displayed above an object, below an object and on both sides. Above and below is an easy thing. But I have some problems with putting the tooltip on a side of the object in a way it is vertically aligned with it. The tooltip can contain different amount of text thus it cannot have a fixed height. This is how it could look like.

HTML

```
<a class="tooltip">object<span>Tooltip text</span></a>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:50px;
}

.tooltip span{
    width: 200px;
    position absolute;
    left: -120px;
    /* No idea what here*/
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to use CSS to determine the height of a sibling. Your best bet is to use javascript.

Comment: I agree.  Without a fixed height, I don't believe this is possible in CSS.  As far as Javascript goes, I would recommend Qtip for this.

Comment: I updated my post. I do not want to use javascript :(

Comment: If you can't use javascript then you have to use tables.